# Redondear esquinas de un layout tipo Dialog

Tags: android, diálogo

Tengo una `Activity` que es un tipo `Dialog` al abrirse y deseo redondear las esquinas en el `Style`

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente, sin embargo no funciona

```
<style name="formularios" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@color/formulario</item>
    <item name="android:radius">@dimen/from</item>
</style>
```

Y en dimens

```
dimen name="from">15dp</dimen>
```

Mi `activity` tiene el tema aplicado de **formularios** que extiende de `Style`.
¿Alguna idea para implementar esto mediante XML o código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937224/3683321) de SO en inglés esto se puede conseguir mediante la creación de un xml que contiene un **shape**.

Este xml deberá estar ubicado en la carpeta `Drawable` y tendrá el siguiente contenido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="30dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Este archivo deberá utilizarse como `background` en el xml del layout de la siguiente forma:

```
android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
```

Y por último poner el `BackgroundDrawable` del `dialog` transparente de la siguiente forma:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

### Documentación

- Recursos de elementos de diseño: [Elemento de diseño de forma](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html?hl=es#Shape)
- Documentación [Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html?hl=es#CustomLayout)
- [Tutorial](http://grishma102.blogspot.com.es/2014/04/android-custom-dialog-example.html) de cómo hacer `Custom Dialog` en el que hay ejemplos de dialogs con bordes redondeados.
- Otra [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12550957/3683321) de SO en inglés que puede serte de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada @FelixBeeb! Espero que te sirva de ayuda